# why is asyncsnapshot.error always returning

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-streambuilder

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../components/grocery_item_tile.dart';
import '../model/cart_model.dart';
import 'cart_page.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    CollectionReference damacanaRef = _firestore.collection("damacana");
    var kaylaRef = damacanaRef.doc("KaylaSu");

    /**
    StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      stream: damacanaRef.snapshots(),
      builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot asyncSnapshot){
        return Scaffold();
      },
    )
        **/
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: damacanaRef.snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext contex, AsyncSnapshot asyncSnapshot){
        ///   List<DocumentSnapshot> listOfDocSnap = asyncSnapshot.data.docs;
        ///   List<DocumentSnapshot> listOfDocSnap = asyncSnapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) => doc as DocumentSnapshot).toList();
        if(asyncSnapshot.hasError){
          return Center(child: Text("Bir Hata ile Karşılaşıldı. Sonra Tekrar Deneyiniz."));
        }else{
          if(asyncSnapshot.hasData){
            List<DocumentSnapshot> listOfDocSnap = asyncSnapshot.data.docs;
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                elevation: 0,
                leading: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.location_on,
                    color: Colors.grey[700],
                  ),
                ),
                title: Text(
                  'Istanbul, Cekmekoy ',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: Colors.grey[700],
                  ),
                ),
                centerTitle: false,
                actions: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 24.0),
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey[200],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                      ),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.person,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                onPressed: () =>
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return CartPage();
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                child: const Icon(Icons.shopping_bag),
              ),
              body: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(height: 48),

// good morning bro
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
                    child: Text('Merhaba,'),
                  ),

                  const SizedBox(height: 4),

// Let's order fresh items for you
                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "Sizin için ürünlerimiz",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 36,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  const SizedBox(height: 24),

                  const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
                    child: Divider(),
                  ),

                  const SizedBox(height: 24),

// categories -> horizontal listview
                   Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "${listOfDocSnap.first}",
                      style: TextStyle(
//fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 18,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

// recent orders -> show last 3
                  Expanded(
                    child: Consumer<CartModel>(
                      builder: (context, value, child) {
                        return GridView.builder(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          itemCount: value.shopItems.length,
                          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            crossAxisCount: 2,
                            childAspectRatio: 1 / 1.2,
                          ),
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return GroceryItemTile(
                              itemName: value.shopItems[index][0],
                              itemPrice: value.shopItems[index][1],
                              imagePath: value.shopItems[index][2],
                              color: value.shopItems[index][3],
                              onPressed: () =>
                                  Provider.of<CartModel>(context, listen: false)
                                      .addItemToCart(index),
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }else{
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
          }
        }


      },
    );
  }
}
```

I am making a market application. I want to pull data from **firebase** and reflect it directly to the screen. it's pulling from the list right now I'm trying to pull data from firebase. code like this. The "Text" message in the async.error structure is always reflected on the screen. How can I solve the error?

Comment: Could you provide the full error log in the console?

Comment: I solved the problem by printing what is the error in the text of "return" thank you